# Count Array in php

Tags: php

if i use the ***count()*** in my php script.Either the value is **zero** also count variable returns 1.why?

```
 Why php count values always returns 1?
```

*Example 1:*

```
$arr = array('php','sql');
echo count($arr);
```

output

```
2
```

*Example 2:*

```
$arr = array('');
echo count($arr);
```

output

```
1
```

even though i count the item in db also it return the same.
example

in my table their is no records

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from table_name");
echo count($query);

output 

1
```

Comment: and why there is no `code` ?

Comment: Please use a more detailed description of your problem. I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Example code? Or your server is haunted.

Comment: Well, comments on SO sometimes really like: *"`Code`! Give us your `Code`!1!!"*. And they are accurate. `(:`

Comment: "If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned."

Answer (score 5):

Because array is not empty

```
php > $array = array('');
php > echo count($array);
1
```

it already has a value a empty string => ""

```
php > print_r($array);
Array
(
    [0] =>
)
```

[count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) does not always return 1, that is pure phallacy, look:

```
php > echo count(array());
0
```

Comment: yep you're filling the first index $array[0]=''; with an empty string

Comment: that was just what i was trying to tell him :)

Comment: lol I know, was just explaining before you edit your post

Comment: $query = mysql_query("select * from table_name");
echo count($query);

output 
1

Comment: don't do `echo count($query)`, try with `print_r($query)`. Maybe that is not a resultset but an error.

Answer (score 0):

- For arrays, `count` returns number of items in array.

  Note, that `array('')` contains *one* item, not zero; the same is true for `array(0)`, `array(null)`, `array(false)`, etc — each of them contains *one* item. Only `array()` contains *zero* items.
- For most of other variable types, `count` almost returns `1`. This is just a design decision — as calling count on "non-countable" values is useless, they'd decided to make it always return one.

  `mysql_query` falls under this case. As `mysql_query` returns not array, but value of [resource type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). Thus `$rsrc = mysql_query('...'); echo count($rsrc);` will always return `1`.
- Also `count` behaves specially for null and objects, see [here](http://www.php.net/count).